# Opencart - how to display products in the menu (column-left) in the parent category?

Tags: menu, opencart

**Opencart** - how to display products in the menu (column-left) in the parent category?

[image: for example]

Comment: did you mean display product under its relevant category in category module? If yes then it is not a good idea as number of products increases the design will look ugly.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I need it in my project. so it will be more usability to the user. Since the product in small quantities.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WJe2p.png